Provisioning status (before running) takes to long
When I run a Pipeline at cloud data fusion, Provisioning status takes at least 3-5 minutes before start running.
Any clues to improve it?
Master Machine Type:e2,Number of masters:1,Master Cores:2,Master Memory (GB):8,Master Disk Size(GB):1000,Worker Cores:2,Worker Memory (GB):8,Worker Disk Size (GB):200,Worker Machine Type:
e2
Increased the Resource driver memory from 2048 to 4096.
